# Is it possible for the graph of a multivariable function to be a curve instead of a surface?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The graph of a function, let's say for example $f: \mathbb{R}^2  \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is a subset of the Cartesian product of the domain and the codomain, in this case of $\mathbb{R}^3$. When speaking about the graph of functions like $f$ the term that is always associated is that one of surface. However i was wondering if there is a possibility that the graph of a function of this type is instead a curve, that can be represented as a vector function $\vec{f}$. For example, a function $F(x, y)$ with the property that the condition of each level set is only satisfied by one point.

$$ F(x, y) = c$$

I imagine that the previous example is not possible, nonetheless i haven't been able to prove it. I don't know if the question is rather trivial, and i have a misconception about the concept of the  graph of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm overlooking something, the graph in ${\mathbb R}^3$ of $z = f(x,y),$ where

$$ f(x,y) \; = \; \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 - 1} \; + \; \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2} $$

is the circle in the $xy$-plane with radius $1$ and center $(0,0,0).$

Note that the domain of $f(x,y)$ is $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ (a circle in the $xy$-plane, not a cylinder in $xyz$-space), and for each point $(a,b)$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ we have $f(a,b) = 0.$

Comment: Thanks, this example is precisely what i was searching in the question

Comment: FYI, I recalled that the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ (over the real numbers) has exactly one solution, namely $(x,y) = (0,0),$ this being an example I often use to show how the usual conclusion that for more variables than equations we might not have infinitely many solutions or even more than one solution (note that the rule holds when the equations are *linear*). Thus, since the graph of a "curve" can be a single point, I felt sure the graph of a "surface" could be a single curve (even a single point if in $f(x,y)$ you replace each of the $1$'s with a $0).$

Comment: This is a nice example, but here we are able to do that because the domain is not $\mathbb{R}^2$, and is instead an one dimensional domain. In fact, the proof i posted on a comment below for this being not possible doesn't apply when you reduce the domain like this case because the segment joining any two points of the domain of $f$ is not on the domain of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a well known result that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, so there is a bijection $h:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Then, for each $c\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists one, and only one point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $h(x,y)=c$.

Anyways, the graph of such a function is obviously very difficult to imagine. So probably if you ask almost any condition over $F$ such as continuity, monotony, or whatever, that won't be possible.

Comment: Thanks i didn't think of the bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2 $ and $\mathbb{R} $. Does that mean, that the graph of a function of two variables can be a curve? If we add continuity as a condition it is still posible to construct such function?

Comment: The graph can be parametrized by the aplication $\varphi(t):=(h(t),t)$, which is not continuous nor differentiable. So, with the common definition of curve, we could say that the graph is not a curve.

Answer (score 1):

I answer here your question in my comment. If we add continuity we cannot construct such a function (the one with level sets consisting of just one point). Let $F:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Applying Intermediate Value Theorem to the single variable functions:
$$g_1(t):=\begin{cases}F((x_1,y_1)+2t\cdot(x_2-x_1,0)) &\text{ if }t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}] \\F((x_1,y_1)+(2t-1)\cdot(0,y_2-y_1)) &\text{ if } t\in(\frac{1}{2},1]\end{cases}\\
g_2(t):=\begin{cases}F((x_1,y_1)+2t\cdot(0,y_2-y_1)) &\text{ if }t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}] \\F((x_1,y_2)+(2t-1)\cdot(x_2-x_1,0)) &\text{ if } t\in(\frac{1}{2},1]\end{cases}$$

We get that for all $y_1\in(g_1(0),g_1(1))$ there exists $c_1\in(0,1)$ such that $g_1(c_1)=y_1$, and for all $y_2\in (g_2(0),g_2(1))$ there exists $c_2\in(0,1)$ such that $g_2(c_2)=y_2$. Note that $g_1(0)=g_2(0)$ and $g_1(1)=g_2(1)$ because of how we defined them, then for every: $$y\in(g_1(0),g_1(1))=(g_2(0),g_2(1))=(F(x_1,y_1),F(x_2,y_2))$$ there exists $c_1,c_2\in(0,1)$ such that $g_1(c_1)=g_2(c_2)=y$. The existence of this implies that there are: $$(a,b)\in L((x_1,x_2),(x_2,y_1))\cup L((x_2,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) \\ (c,d)\in L((x_1,y_1),(x_1,y_2))\cup L((x_1,y_2),(x_1,y_2))$$
(where $L((u,v),(w,z)):=\{(u,v)+t\cdot (w-y,z-v) : t\in[0,1]\}$ is the segment joining two points).

Such that $F(a,b)=y=F(c,d)$. This makes impossible what we want.